# Firebase toObject with ref

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

With cloud firestore, you can convert a document to your object with `document.toObject(YourClass.class);` where the class's variables match those in your database.  However, if one of the variables in the database is a reference, which data type would you use in the java class?  Note that I need to not only store it in my data model but retrieve it and set it with the override methods of the form:

```
protected MyDataModel(Parcel in) {
    mString = in.readString();
}
```

and

```
@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
    parcel.writeString(mString);
}
```

If I use a DocumentReference, then in writeToParcel(), how would I write it?  Also, how would I read it in the protected `Parcel in` constructor?  I have tried `writeSerializable()` and `readSerializable()` but `DocumentReference` does not implement `Serializable`.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used the Java API yet but I imagine you'll want to use the DocumentReference type. Here are some links in the firebase documentation:
[DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference)

[CollectionReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/CollectionReference)

[getDocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot.html#getDocumentReference(java.lang.String))

Comment: Edited question because I do not know how to use the override methods with a DocumentReference since it doesn't implement Serializable.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to serialize a DocumentReference, use its [getPath()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference.html#getPath()) method to get a string that describes the document's location in the database.  To deserialize that path string back into a DocumentReference, use [FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().document(path)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FirebaseFirestore.html#document(java.lang.String)).

When you have conversions like this to make, sometimes it more convenient to write all the code yourself rather than using the built-in object serialization provided by the Firestore SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with `document.toObject(YourClass.class);`
I have an `Event` class, this class contains the `id` (document id) and a reference to another collection `subCategoryReference`.

I have created simples converters on my `Event`

For example:

```
val event = document
      .toObject(Event::class.java)
      .withId<Event>(document.id)
      .withReference<Event>((document.data["subCategoryReference"] as DocumentReference).path)
```

In my Event class as you guessed I have two function `withId` and `withReference`
that look like this:

```
fun <T : Event?> withId(id: String): T {
  this.id = id
  return this as T
}

fun <T : Event?> withReference(reference: String): T {
  this.subCategoryRef = reference
  return this as T
}
```

**Your class variables must have different names from your firestore variables/fields (just the variables you want to apply the converter on)** - see the pic below

In my case on firestore, the reference field (variable) called `subCategoryReference` and in the `Event` class the variable name is `subCategoryRef`.

Let me know if you didn't get me.

I hope it helps...

**Firestore console**
[image: Firestore console]

**`Event` Class**
[image: Event Class]